# Redux Reducer - Add to Cart Action Functionality with Conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When the product is in the cart the both conditions return **empty** array for the cart.
The cart has **3** objects: **the product, quantity, and variants** (which are color and size)
Any help please

```
// Cart reducer

const shopReducer = (state = INITSTATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      const product = state.products.find((p) => p.id === action.payload.id);
      const inCart =
        state.cart.find((item) => item)?.product.id === action.payload.id
          ? //state.cart.map((item) => item?.product.id === action.payload.id)
            true
          : false;
      if (inCart)
        state.cart.map((item) => {
          if (
            item.product.id === action.payload.id &&
            item.setVar === action.payload.setVar
          )
            return {
              ...state,
              cart: {...item, quantity: item.quantity+1},
            };
          else
            return {
              ...state,
              cart: [
                ...state.cart,
                { product: product, quantity: 1, setVar: action.payload.setVar },
              ],
            }
  
        });
      else
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [
            {
              product: product,
              quantity: 1,
              setVar: action.payload.setVar,
            },
          ],
        };
   }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the answer below, just the FYI: this is an extremely outdated style of Redux and something like that could be done in a 5-line-reducer with modern Redux - in modern `createSlice` reducers you are allowed to just modify the `state` object.
Please read up on [why Redux Toolkit is Redux nowadays](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) (since 2019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the result of the map. Try doing this

```
  return state.cart.map((item) => ...
```